# Start Activity Intent from Android Application

Tags: android-activity, android

I have an activity that holds a handler that I need to be running for the whole app. What I need to do is call the handler activity whenever main activity starts up, then upon executing a function at handler activity, handler activity should start the intent into second activity.

This is my code:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

    public void onCreate() {
        h = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Bundle b = msg.getData();
                Log.d("tag",b.getString("msg"));

                //THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO OPEN SECONDACTIVITY
        }
     };
   }
}
```

MyApp is a global Application class I use to run a socket connection across the whole app. It needs to be alive as long as the app is running.

Comment: Can you explain bit more what exactly  you want to do.

Comment: what u exactly want to do dude

Comment: `Application` is not an `Activity`. Try to start from MainActivity.

Comment: @PankajKumar Yes I know. But after executing a method at MyApp Application, I need to open another Activity.

Comment: @jeraldov Ok. go ahead and do it..

Answer (score 1):

Its simple

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivityClass.this, SECONDACTIVITY.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   public class MyApp extends Application {

        public void onCreate() {
            h = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                Bundle b = msg.getData();


                Log.d("tag",b.getString("msg"));
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, YourSecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        };


        }
    }
```

Also add this to your manifest file

```
 <activity android:name=".YourSecondActivity" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, It turns out that I need to add: `i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`

```
Intent i = new Intent(MyApp.this, SecondActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

Because From MainActivity, I called MyApp (An class to maintain global application state). Then in MyApp, I process something and then I call SecondActivity.

Comment: Sorry, this makes no sense. Can you elaborate? You shouldn't need to set `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` unless you are launching an `Activity` but not from an `Activity` context (ie: from a `Service` or a `BroadcastReceiver`

Comment: Well, MyApp isn't an activity. It an Android Application Class.

Comment: Yes, but you can call methods on it from an Activity and those would be called in an Activity context.

Comment: Its because the Application Class is doing methods in a handler. And also, I couldn't remember the error that came up in logcat but is related to Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.

Answer (score 0):

First You add the activity information in AndroidManifest.xml LIKE

```
<activity
    android:name="com.assignment.matchnumber.PlayActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.assignment.matchnumber.PLAY" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Then put this in your MyApp activity where you want.

```
Intent openPlayActivity = new Intent("com.assignment.matchnumber.PLAY");
startActivity(openPlayActivity);
```

thanks
--Sajib